# .NET Core: alter build process to execute a script

Tags: .net-core

How to instruct the build process to run a `cmd` or `PowerShell` command/script before or after specific project in .NET Core solution?

I want this command to be executed regardless of the build environment (Visual Studio, `dotnet` command, or TFS builder).

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts is the extension point. I did not see the documentation page before asking the question.

Comment: Link-only answers are a bad idea because the link eventually disappears. There's also no way to up-down vote the contents because they might change. Please summarize the essential items from the link and put that as the answer.

Comment: This is a bad answer. You are not posting anything relevant and now the link is broken!